# How to design a controller at ASP.NET MVC that has an action in relation with other controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture, software-design

I'm working on a project that has many modules and some modules have relation with others. For example, I have a `Meeting` module. Users can request meetings and create agendas for them. On the other hand, there is a `Balloting` module. Users can create and publish ballots. While requesting a meeting at some point a balloting starts.

Here is the point that I have struggle. `Meeting` and `Ballot` modules has its own controllers. Now, I have an action in `BallotController` and `MeetingController` uses that to start a balloting session. In `BallotController` the action that starts the session requests controller name and some other info like `Id` of the meeting request. In that action I have a switch that controls the Controller name and sets the relation with it in the database.

I have many modules that uses `Ballot` module and other modules. I want to make a central system or any other ideas to make this sequence as systemmatic as possible. I don't know if it is appropriate to make a new action for each controller for that process.

If you can share any best practices I'll be appreciated.

Edit: I am calling other controllers from the view.

Comment: I can't really make sense of your architecture based on your description sorry, but a hunch is that your controllers are doing a bit too much? Does that sound right? In my opinion, controllers should be a thin facade to whatever business logic you need to call, and that business logic _can_ be shared between controllers (if necessary).

Comment: Think of controllers as "the resource" and controller actions as "something that can be done to that resource". Controllers shouldn't ever be calling each other as they exist purely to facilitate a web route. Any processing should be done in one or more services that the controllers consume.

Comment: you should provide relevant code, but your controllers purpose is to consume requests and send back responses. You should decouple your business logic from the controllers

Comment: I am calling controllers from views. The flow is like MeetingController().CreateMeeting() -> Meeting/CreateMeeting view -> BallotController().StartBallotting() -> return Meeting/Index.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Yes, my controllers are working as you described. Now my flow is this, Controller starts a View then from the View call another controller after finish the process return first called View.

Comment: @Kevin Sorry but the code I am working on has so many pieces. So I couldn't add.